# Why the two html elements not aligned to each other after adding CSS?

Tags: html, css, frontend

```css
#four {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.input input {
  height: 1.8vw;
  width: 10vw;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 120px;
  border-radius: 1.5vw / 100%;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.input .go {
  width: 2.3vw;
  height: 1.8vw;
  border-radius: 1.5vw / 100%;
  background-color: hsl(12, 88%, 59%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.7vw;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='four'>
  <div class='input'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='Email..' spellcheck='false'>
    <div class='go'>Go</div>
  </div>
  <p>Copyright 2020. All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>
```

The output of the code is ,

[image: rendered output]

I dont understand why the input div and go button are not aligned to each other? Why the button div is positioned slightly downward?

Comment: I created a snippet from your code, it doesn't look like the picture you provided. Can you update the snippet so we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have reproduced the corrected result with *minimal code* here. You can style it your way and can see for yourself where the problem was.

**HTML code**

```html
<div id='four'>
  <div class='input'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='Email..' spellcheck='false'>
  </div>
  <div class='go'>Go</div>
</div>
 <p>Copyright 2020. All Rights Reserved</p>
```

**CSS code**

```
body{
  background:black;
}
#four {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
input[type='text']{
  padding:7px;
  margin-right:5px;
  border-radius:14px;
  border:none;
}
.go{
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:14px;
  background:#f64;
  color:white;
}
p{
  color:white;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `flex-direction: row;` it'll be fine.

```css
        #four {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.input input {
  height: 1.8vw;
  width: 10vw;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 120px;
  border-radius: 1.5vw / 100%;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.input .go {
  width: 2.3vw;
  height: 1.8vw;
  border-radius: 1.5vw / 100%;
  background-color: hsl(12, 88%, 59%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.7vw;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='four'>
        <div class='input'>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Email..' spellcheck='false'>
          <div class='go'>Go</div>
        </div>
        <p>Copyright 2020. All Rights Reserved</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i change your `css` code and it work correct . you should change `display : inline`  in .go `css` .

```css
        #four {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-end;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
        
        .input input {
            height: 1.8vw;
            width: 10vw;
            min-height: 20px;
            min-width: 120px;
            border-radius: 1.5vw / 100%;
            border: none;
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        
        .input .go {
            width: 2.3vw;
            height: 1.8vw;
            border-radius: 1.5vw / 100%;
            background-color: hsl(12, 88%, 59%);
            color: white;
            font-size: 0.7vw;
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<div id='four'>
        <div class='input'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Email..' spellcheck='false'>
            <div class='go'>Go</div>
        </div>
        <p>Copyright 2020. All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
```